# Android Navigation Drawer in Deep Navigation

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My app is using the new Navigation Drawer  in the layout of the root Activity.  Each of the items in the drawer is a fragment (just like the example project demonstrates).  However, I have deeper navigation, and the guidelines state,
"If you have particularly deep branches, navigating to the top-level of your app can become repetitive and cumbersome with Up and Back alone. Since navigation drawers are accessible from anywhere in the app, navigation up to the top level is faster and more efficient,"
implying that the drawer should be accessible via a swipe from the left side of the screen almost anywhere in the app (see Play Music for an example), not just at the root Activity.

Since my deeper navigation includes new Activities, not just more fragments stacked, how can I still apply my main Navigation Drawer to enable quicker navigation to the top items (fragments) throughout my app?

Comment: Include the navigation drawer in all the sub-activities too.

Comment: I would need to replicate a lot of code and layout to do that, though.  Which is okay; I just want to make sure that that is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Google definitely did a poor job of explaining this one, as it took me awhile to find it myself. The proper way to handle this is using [FragmentTransactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) to add/replace containers within your existing nav drawer layout, particularly the [`addToBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) method to tell Android to treat it like a navigation transaction.

I had to piece this together from their article, [Providing Proper Back Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments) which explains how it's done for Fragments. One cool tidbit is that you don't have to "add" Fragments on top of each other, you can just replace the active one. When the user hits "Back", Android's [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) will pop the transaction and reverse it back to the previous state.

Furthermore, you'll probably also want to call [`setTransition(int transit)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setTransition(int)) on your transaction for it to animate like an activity would. Here's an example of what I use in my projects:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                    .addToBackStack(null);
                    .commit();
```

Hitting "Back" from this will perform the opposite animation and return to the previous state before the transaction occurred.

I know I'm late but hope it helps someone!